# Upload image to facebook stagging and get back the uri of uploaded image

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

My goal is to upload an image to facebook stagging and get back the uri of the uploaded image which later i want to use to create an open graph story. My tools are c# / javascript.

I am trying to send an image to facebook stagging. Documentation mentioned the curl but not able to find any way of doing the following curl with facebbok javascript or the c# sdk.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://graph.facebook.com/me/staging_resources \
  -F "file=@images/prawn-curry-1.jpg" \
  -F "access_token=$USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Below is my c# code

```
    byte[] imgbytes = imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Request.MapPath("/fbimages") + "/Desert.jpg"));
    Facebook.FacebookClient fbClient = new Facebook.FacebookClient();
    Facebook.FacebookClient.DefaultVersion = "v2.5";
    fbClient.AppId = FacebookApplicationSettings.AppId;
    fbClient.AppSecret = FacebookApplicationSettings.AppSecret;
    fbClient.AccessToken = SessionValues.AccessToken;
    string URL = "https://graph.facebook.com//me/staging_resources";
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["file"] = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(imgbytes);
    fbClient.Post(URL, parameters);
```

and java script code

```
function UploadTheImgToFB()
    {
            FB.api(
            '/me/staging_resources',
            'post',
            {
             'file':'/fbimages/Desert.jpg'
            },

            function(response) {
            // handle the response
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.uri);
                    if (response && !response.error_message) {
                    // then get post content
                    //alert('successfully posted. Status id : '+response.id);
                } else {
                    //alert('Something went error.');
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

none of the above codes work against the given curl.

I am getting this error

> (#100) Invalid file. Expected file of one of the following types: image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png

How can i do this curl in c# or javascript facebook api?

Comment: I am just looking for some solution to post an image to facebook stagging, and get back the uploaded image uri. My project is in c#, I hope someone can help me!